# What percentage of answers to this question are correct?

Tags: probability, logic

I have the following question:

> What percentage of answers to this question are correct?
> a) 50%
> b) 25%
> c) 0%
> d) 50%

My ideia is the following:

> If I say that "a)" is the correct one, thus we have 50% of chance of having the right answer since we have "a)" and "d)" equals to 50%, that is 2 answers out of 4 correct, 50%, which is true.

> If  "b)" is correct, then it is already true since "b)" is 1 out of 4, 25%.

> "c)" can't be because if it is right, it will be already 25% of the answers.

> If "d)" is right, it occurs the same as "a)", true.

Hence, we have 3 possible right answers, thus the percentage is 3/4, 75%.

Is that the case?

Comment: Well if $75\%$ are correct, that's not an option, so you'd have to bring in a fifth option, which would mean $80\%$ of the answers are correct...

Comment: There is no scenario where a, b, and d are simultaneously correct. Either a and d are correct or b is correct but we can't tell which option is true. Since we don't have enough information to answer the question, the best we can do is rule out c.

Answer (score 1):

The intended answer is b.  You are supposed to assume that there is one correct answer out of four, so that is $25\%$.  $50\%$ would only be right if both a and d were correct, but questions are supposed to have only one correct answer unless specified.  c cannot be correct because if it were $25\%$ of the answers would be correct.

Comment: Yes you're right, but how about "c)" can't be right? Thus it shouldn't be 25%, but 33%

Comment: You are given four answers and asked what fraction are right.  I claim neither a nor d is right either, so by your logic it should be $100\%$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: On the other hand, the wording of the question certainly suggests that more than one answer could be correct, and then things get very interesting. An answer key that says that b) is correct would make b) correct, but an answer key that says that a) and d) are correct would make a) and d) correct. Thus, $75\%$ of the answers are potentially correct, and $75\%$ isn’t available, so an argument can even be made that c) is correct. I consider the question hopelessly flawed.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  I haven't seen the answer key.  Would you like to bet on what it says?  I would take b at even money.  I agree the question is a mess.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Even if I were a betting person, I wouldn’t bet on it without seeing other questions from the same source to get some feel for just how clever the author thinks he is!